# Disable Primefaces Spinner Clientside

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

on my Website I have two radio buttons in a Group. One for a time range and one for a number input. For the date range, I use two p:calender widgets and for the number a p:spinner.

Now I want to disable the p:spinner if the radio button for the date range was clicked. I know that this can be done serverside, but I want to save some traffic to the server, so I want to to this on the client side.

My first idea was to use jQuery. I know how to disable the input field of the spinner, and set the ui-class so that it looks like it is invisible, but the spinner buttons (up and down) are still active (they don't look like that, but i can click on them)

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Here's my code:

#### xhtml

```
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" layout="custom" value="all">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="opt1" itemValue="all" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="opt2" itemValue="random" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="opt3" itemValue="range" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
        <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Alle" />
        <p:outputLabel value="&nbsp;" />

        <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
        <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="Anzahl" />
        <p:spinner placeholder="42" min="1" id="random" disabled="true"/>

        <p:radioButton id="opt3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" />
        <h:outputLabel for="opt3" value="Zeitraum" />
        <h:panelGroup id="range">
            <p:calendar placeholder="24.12.2014" locale="de" />
            <p:calendar placeholder="24.12.2014" locale="de" />
        </h:panelGroup>
     </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='inputForm:customRadio']").change(radioValueChanged);
});

function radioValueChanged() {
    radioValue = $(this).val();

    if (radioValue == "all") {
        toggleRandomInput(false);
        $("#inputForm\\:range").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else if (radioValue == "random") {
        toggleRandomInput(true);
        $("#inputForm\\:range").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else if (radioValue == "range") {
        toggleRandomInput(false);
        $("#inputForm\\:range").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}

function toggleRandomInput(active) {
    if (active) {
        $("#inputForm\\:random").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $("#inputForm\\:random_input").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#inputForm\\:random_input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#inputForm\\:random").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    }
}
```

---

## Solution

#### xhtml

```
...
<h:outputScript library="js" name="simSettings.js" target="body" />
...

<p:selectOneRadio id="rdoGrp_filter" layout="custom" value="#{simulation.filter_selectedFilter}" 
    widgetVar="rdoGrp_filter">
...
<p/selectOneRadio>

<p:radioButton id="rdo_changed" for="rdoGrp_filter" itemIndex="2" />
<h:outputLabel for="rdo_changed" value="#{sim.filter_range}" />
```

#### JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        rdoGrp_filter.jq.change(radioValueChanged);
        toggleRandomInput(false);

        // Exception rdoGrp_filter is not defined is thrown
    });

    function toggleCalendar(active) {
        if (active) {
            cal_from.disable();
            cal_from.jq.removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            cal_to.disable();
            cal_to.jq.removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        } else {
            cal_from.enable();
            cal_from.jq.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            cal_to.enable();
            cal_to.jq.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        }
    }

    function toggleRandomInput(active) {
        if (active) {
            spin_random.jq.removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
            spin_random.input.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
            spin_random.bindEvents();
        } else {
            spin_random.jq.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            spin_random.input.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            spin_random.upButton.unbind();
            spin_random.downButton.unbind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a util functions ;)

```
function disableSpinner(spinnerObject) {
    spinnerObject.input.attr('disable', 'disable');
    spinnerObject.jq.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    spinnerObject.upButton.unbind('mousedown.spinner')
    spinnerObject.downButton.unbind('mousedown.spinner')
}

function enableSpinner(spinnerObject) {
   spinnerObject.input.removeAttr('disable', 'disable');
   spinnerObject.jq.removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
   spinnerObject.bindEvents()
}
```

---

***xhtml***

```
<p:spinner widgetVar="spinnerWV" placeholder="42" min="1" id="random" />
```

Then simply in your `toggleRandomInput` function:

```
function toggleRandomInput(active) {
   if (active) {
       enableSpinner(PF('spinnerWV'));//assuming that your spinner widgetVar is spinnerWV
   } else {
       disableSpinner(PF('spinnerWV'));//assuming that your spinner widgetVar is spinnerWV
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,
this might be helpful (I can't prove it at the moment). But I have one question. What is spinnerWV? If I use jQuery, can I use spinnerWV = $("#SpinnerID")?

And what is bindEvents()? I googled, but I can't find any reference

Comment: spinnerWV is the widgetVar of your spinner component .. I'll edit my answer so you can see what I mean by the widgetVar .. as for the Javascript API of PrimeFaces, you can't find any reference online on that .. it's a debugging experience ..

Comment: you cloud also refer to this article, http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/

Comment: I've added a Solution to my question, but it does not really work. I got a Exception (rdoGrp_filter is not defined) int the $(document).ready() function. I think it's thrown because Primevaces is not allready initialized. Do you have an idea, how to solve that problem?

Comment: I changed the widgetVars to *_var, but the error is still the same.

Comment: try to use this, `setTimeout(rdoGrp_filter_var.jq.change(radioValueChanged), 2000);`

Comment: I've solved it myselv. I put the `<h:outputScript library="js" name="simSettings.js" target="body" />` in the body. Now it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Further to @hatem-aliman's answer, I found that the lines

```
spinnerObject.input.attr('disable', 'disable');
```

and

```
spinnerObject.input.removeAttr('disable', 'disable');
```

no longer work. You can use

```
spinnerObject.input.prop("disabled", true);
```

and

```
spinnerObject.input.prop("disabled", false);
```

instead.